# How to set 2 user variables in importing csv to mysql? (LOAD DATA INFILE)

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to import csv file to mysql. But I do not know how to set 2 user variables. I've searched everywhere and only 1 SET user variables are there.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/ks-projects-201612.csv' 
INTO TABLE ks_projects_201612
CHARACTER SET latin1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(id,project_name,sub_category,main_category,currency,@deadline,target,launched,pledge,state,backers,country,usd_pledged,dummy1,dummy2,dummy3,dummy4) 
SET deadline = date_format(str_to_date(@deadline, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i')
SET launched= date_format(str_to_date(@launched, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i');
```

Comment: Look at the [reference manual for LOAD DATA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html), `SET` variables are comma separated.

Comment: Hi @danblack. Used that and it worked. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the `SET` and documentations provided by @danblack.
`Look at the reference manual for LOAD DATA, SET variables are comma separated`
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html